# Why does the DSN (which is stored on the network) only work on my PC and not for others on our network?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, dsn

I created an Access DB on the server which accesses data in the SQL Server 2014 (Express) via a DSN. This works perfectly from my PC but when others attempt to open the Access DB, it can't locate the files.

I did a lot of research on using a connection string but I can't seem to get that in place either.

I have tried 2 avenues, DSN and Connection string.I will describe both. A solution for either will be much appreciated.

DSN: I copied the DSN folder which was located in mydocuments\mydatasources to the same location on the server where the Access DB resides (on the F: drive). Everyone on the network has access to this location.
Then I went into the Linked Table Manager in the Access DB and set the location using that DSN. 
I also went into the properties of the DSN folder on the F: drive and made sure all had security access to the folder.
But when any one else attempts to open the Access DB it gives the error that it can't locate one of the tables which is supposed to be displayed on the initial screen.

Connection String: I located this site which has much information on connections strings.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2014/
This site provides the connection string but i am having trouble get the correct VBA to use it. My current attempt is shown in the next section. The (run-time 3265) error I get is this...
"item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal"
Debug shows it halted on the Properties("Data Provider") line.

```
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim sConnString As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "FS01\PRACTICECS\PRACTICECS"
Database_Name = "CSP_507483_Merlinos"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
   With Cn
      .Properties("Data Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB"
      .Properties("Data Source").Value = "FS01\PRACTICECS\PRATICECS"
      .Properties("Integrated Security").Value = True
      .Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "CSP_507483_Merlinos"
      .CommandTimeout = 120
      .ConnectionTimeout = 120
      .Open
   End With
```

The results are above. At this point, I don't care which method I use so help on either would be appreciated.

Comment: You have User DSN and System DSN.  A User DSN will only work for a specific user while System is intended for multiple people.

Comment: Not an answer but I'd strongly advice you to split your Access database in frontend and backend.

Comment: Thank you smoore4. Where in the code do i specify "System DSN"? Your answer may also apply to my update to this post. I changed the connection string to the following: 'sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=FS01\PRACTICECS;Initial Catalog=CSP_507483_Merlinos"' I get this error :run-time error Cannot open database "CSP_507483_Merlinos" requested by the login. The login failed"

Comment: Thank you too Rene. I do intend to split the database before deployment

Answer (score 2):

Well, first your posted code is going to do nothing, since you create a connection object, but such connection objects are ONLY for use if you create an ADODB reocrdset in code – has ZERO relationship to the linked tables.

Next up:
Do not use a system DSN, or a USER DSN. Both of these in fact rely on editing the registry, so they should be avoided.

Always, but always use a FILE DSN.

However, keep in mind that Access ALWAYS by default converts a FILE DSN connection to what we call DSN-LESS.

This effect is VERY good and VERY BAD.

The very good part:
Once you link tables using the FILE DSN, then Access will have converted the FILE DSN to DSN less.

This is good because from THEN ONWARDS, the FILE DSN is not used. The file DSN settings are ignored. And in fact you can delete the DSN you created and Access will still function and work just fine.

So, keep in mind that FILE dsn’s are ONLY USED one time at linking, and after the tables are linked, then you do NOT need the FILE dsn, and in fact THEY ARE 100% IGNORED AND NOT USED!!!!

So, what this means?

Link the database using a FILE dsn, and ensue that the linked tables work. If AFTER linking using the FILE dsn, you should be able to shut down and exit the application. When you re-launch the application, then your linked tables should work just fine.

The above thus means that now ANY user opening the database should find that that the linked tables work. At this point, then you can copy and distribute this front end to each workstation. As I stated, the DSN is 100% ignored and IS NOT USED by Access (assuming you created a FILE dsn here – don’t use system, or user – they require the registry and settings and entrees to be made in the registry).

However, it not clear if your connections and you are using SQL logons, or windows authentication? A MASSIVE EARTH shattering issue and detail you left out.

If you are using windows authentication, then of course each user will have to be given rights by your system administrator, and such rights are given by use of “active directory”, or what we call a “domain server”. This means that you not be using SQL server logons, nor using SQL server to manage user rights.

However, if you using SQL logons, and it is a common practice for all uses to use the SAME user + logon for Access linked tables, then once again the above “DSN-LESS” approach is achieved by ALWAYS BUT ALWAYS using and linking tables with a FILE DSN.

So, just be sure that you use Access to launch the control panel, and be 100% sure you create the new DSN this way. Thus, once you linked your tables, then in fact the FILE is 100% ignored, can be deleted, and is not required.

Do keep in mind that the type of connection you created MAY WELL require to you to install the ODBC drivers on each workstation. You will NOT have to copy, nor setup, nor use, nor have the DSN on each workstation.

So, if you link using the native 11, (or 12, or 13) drivers, then such drivers MUST be installed on each workstation.

You can of course use the standard “SQL server driver” and this “legacy” driver will have been installed on each and every workstation.

And, as noted, you should be placing a copy of the front end on each workstation.

Comment: Thank you @smoore4  My code now looks like this:  sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=FS01\PRACTICECS;Initial Catalog=CSP_507483_Merlinos"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
 With Cn
.Open
End With

Comment: All, please forgive my stumbling in comment format. I am repeating my question to you @smoore4. Thank you.  Where in the code do i specify "System DSN"?  
 Your answer may also apply to my update to this post. I changed the connection string to the following: 'sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=FS01\PRACTICECS;Initial Catalog=CSP_507483_Merlinos"'  I get this error:  run-time error Cannot open database "CSP_507483_Merlinos" requested by the login. The login failed"

Comment: Albert, although the sarcasm is not necessary, I do very  much appreciate your insight. 
For ongoing maintenance reasons, I prefer not to distribute the front end to each workstation but rather have them access the Access frontend directly which resides on the server. Your last statement says that I should be placing a copy on each workstation. Why do you feel this is recommended?
I intend to use windows authentication. The users are already accessing this SQL server via the vendor’s front end (which is Practice CS)
Where do I specify the “FILE” DSN?

Comment: Albert, also I don't understand your first paragraph because I did create the ADODB record set  "Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset". Am I missing something in your comment?

Comment: Albert is absolutely correct in recommending the front-end be placed on individual user workstations.  Having multiple users connected to the same front-end simultaneously causes frequent corruption.  Front-ends will even get corrupted occasionally when run only from a single user's workstation.  That's an easy issue to deal with, though, if they can just grab a clean copy from a network folder when it does happen.

Comment: I want to thank all for your comments. I can't seem to get the DSN to work on other machines. Even if I create it under the "File" tab (which is how I am interpreting Albert;s suggestion) when I look at the DSN file in notepad, it still has my workstation ID and user name.

Comment: I have decided to attempt the connection string instead. Since the leading question on this DSN related, I will create a new question. Thank you again for your comments

Comment: Remember, by using a FILE dsn, then Access ONLY uses that DSN one time when you link the tables. After that, the  DSN is not used and ignored by Access. So, there is no question as to where the FILE DSN should be on each workstation, since as I pointed out the FILE dsn is not used by Access, except ONE TIME when you link the table. So, you can't ask nor need to ask where the FILE dsn should be, since it not used anymore. And this is great, since all users thus will not   need or be using the DSN, since your connection is now DSN-LESS.

Comment: And you REALLY but REALLY want to let Access launch the ODBC panel, and THEN create the FILE dsn. Doing it this way means you get the DSN-less connection, but also ensure that the connection works.  So, you MUST do this on a workstation, and once the connection works, then it will work on all workstations

Comment: Why place application on each workstation? Your IT folks installed word on each workstation for the last 20 years. Where has your IT department installed the PDF viewer program for the last 20 years? (answer: on each workstation). You can certainly share say a word file, or a pdf file on the server but the application part is installed on each workstation. So, now just because YOU decide to start developing software, why out of the blue would you change your IT policy of 20+ years of installing software on each workstation like everyone on planet earth has been doing for the last 20 years?